# WildFly Cluster MarshallableUserObject

Tags: java, wildfly, load-balancing, infinispan

I have a Java application running on WildFly 25 on AWS. We are trying to set up High Availability with two nodes using Infinispan cache to replicate the session between nodes.

**web.xml**

```
<!-- cluster-aware -->
<distributable/>
```

**distributable-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<distributable-web xmlns="urn:jboss:distributable-web:2.0">
    <infinispan-session-management cache-container="web" cache="corpapp-session-cache-web" granularity="SESSION">
        <no-affinity/>
    </infinispan-session-management>
</distributable-web>
```

**standalone-ha.xml**

```
  <cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist" marshaller="PROTOSTREAM" modules="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
    <distributed-cache name="corpapp-session-cache-web">
      <file-store path="corpapp-cache" passivation="false" purge="false" shared="false"/>
    </distributed-cache>
  </cache-container>
```

Start each node:

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-ha.xml -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=600 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0;
```

We basically followed this: https://octopus.com/blog/wildfly-jdbc-ping

When the load balancers health check runs and pings every 2 seconds, the following warning is logged:

**Warninng**

```
WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (default task-37) ISPN000559: Cannot marshall 'class org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject': java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object

Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in object java.lang.Object@78d852b1
    in object java.util.HashMap@81917a8
    in object java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@d0c8938
```

**Question**

How do I resolve this?

The stack trace indicates that this is all from WildFly/Infinispan.

Comment: Perhaps it's just warning, but clusterSingleton failover doesn't work. ISPN000559: Cannot marshall 'class org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject': java.io.NotSerializableException: org.wildfly.clustering.server.provider.CopyOnWriteAddressSetRemoveFunction  Have you any answer?